# Template functions and types in C#

Tags: c#, template-function

Hello I am having some difficulty with setting up a class , because of the types involved.
Here is the Idea:

class A has a private arraylist which is supposed to be filled with instances of class B.
So any instance of class A will have its on ArrayList of class B elements.
class A has a function to add to its ArrayList a new instance of B. To be more specific, inside the A.Add, a new B is instantiated, and initialized, then added to the ArrayList.
class B is a very simple class: It has one enum Type in it, and it **should** also contain a reference to an external object/class or whatever.
Suppose there are classes * appleClass, peachClass , lemonClass * and classB is the fruit class, and class A is the fruitBasket. The everytime the main code sees a fruit, it should ask class A to add it in the basket. that means, A.add(**thisfruit**), but this fruit might be any of the fruitclasses. which in turn means that I need a generic signature to instantiate classB , and add it to A.arraylist. I don;t know if I make any sense but I will also try to give some code to explain my problem.

```
class Lemon
{
    //....
}
class Apple
{
    //....
}
class Peach
{
    //....
}

class Fruit
{
    public int color;
    <T> fruit;///this should be the <T> type depending on the fruit class i am adding
    public Fruit(T f, int c){fruit = f; color = c;}
}

class Basket
{
    ArrayList FruitArray= new ArrayList();
    public void AddFruit<T>(T f,int c )
    {
        fru = new Fruit(f,c);
        FruitArray.Add(fru);
    }
}
```

SomeHow I should use templates?? I know the code above is wrong, but I can't figure how is this best done.

Thank You

Alex

*EDIT*
Thank You all for your answers. They all seem to point to using a base/abstract class Fruit, and derive specific fruits from it. I am sorry to tell you that my actuall project doesn't involve fruits, I just used them for simplicity. The actual project is in **Unity** and somr of the "fruits" are coming from Unity classes , some other "Fruits" are my own classes. this means that I can't declare parent class for the ones that come from Unity's namespace. I was more hopeing to be able to have a generic reference to the "fruit" , that would be a void pointer in good old C. I know C# is strongly typed, and won't allow most pointer-like uses, but there must me a way to pass an "unknown" reference-to-object to a class/function and use/resolve it later...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT to reflect the new information in your question:**
An ArrayList is a good way to proceed, but I wouldn't use generics in this case since it is going to cause a lot of headaches and code duplication. Instead, I would use reflection to find and invoke the correct overload *at runtime*. A snippet of code is worth one thousand words, so here's a simple console application to show this:

```
class ObjectA {
    public int A { get; set; }
    public ObjectA( int a ) {
        this.A = a;
    }
}

class ObjectB {
    public int B { get; set; }
    public ObjectB( int b ) {
        this.B = b;
    }
}

class ObjectC {
    public int C { get; set; }
    public ObjectC( int c ) {
        this.C = c;
    }
}

class DynamicOverloadResolution {
    ArrayList items;

    public DynamicOverloadResolution( ) {
        items = new ArrayList( ) { 
            new ObjectA( 1 ), new ObjectB( 2 ), new ObjectC( 3 )
        };
    }

    public void ProcessObjects( ) {
        foreach ( object o in items )
            processObject( o );
    }

    private void processObject( object o ) {
        Type t = typeof( DynamicOverloadResolution );
        IEnumerable<MethodInfo> processMethods = t.GetMethods( )
            .Where( m => m.Name == "process" );

        foreach(MethodInfo info in processMethods) {
            if ( info.GetParameters( ).First( ).ParameterType == o.GetType( ) )
                info.Invoke( this, new object[ ] { o } );
        }
    }

    public void process( ObjectA a ) { Console.WriteLine( a.A ); }
    public void process( ObjectB b ) { Console.WriteLine( b.B ); }
    public void process( ObjectC c ) { Console.WriteLine( c.C ); }
}

class Program {
    static void Main( string[ ] args ) {
        var d = new DynamicOverloadResolution( );
        d.ProcessObjects( );
    }
}
```

And here's the output:

```
1
2
3
```

**Old Answer:**

You can simply make fruit an abstract class or an interface, have everything inherit from/implement it and keep a list of fruit:

```
interface IFruit {
    public int c { get; set; }
}

class Apple : IFruit { }
class Peach : IFruit { }
class Lemon : IFruit { }

class Basket {
    List<IFruit> fruitList = new List<IFruit>();

    public void AddIFruit<T>(int c) 
        where T : IFruit, new {

        var f = new T();
        f.c = c;
        fruitList.Add(f);
    }
}
```

It is possible to know the exact type of the elements you get out from the list with the operator [is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx):

```
var f = fruitList.First();
if(f is Apple) { }
else if(f is Peach) { }
else if(f is Lemon) { }
```

In alternative, you can use the [as](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) operator to convert from IFruit to one of its implementations (beware, the result will be null if the conversion is not possible, i.e. you used wrong types):

```
List<Fruit>a=Basket.GetFruits();
switch(a[0].c) { 
    case 0:
        Lemon L = a[0] as Lemon;
}
```

But if you need to do this, then maybe you are approaching the problem from a wrong perspective.

Comment: Thank You @BlackBear for answering. Another thing : if I use this way you suggest, when I get back from A the list(in my main code) I need to know the exact type(fruit) that each element is. Will this be possible? I don't want to just know that it is of type "Fruit".. I want top know if it is a lemon or an apple.
example:

List<Fruit>a=Basket.GetFruits();
switch(a[0].c)
{
 case 0:
{
Lemon L= a[0].f;// fill this be ok??? will f be of type lemon?
}
//....

}

Comment: @Sagi2313 it took me a while, but you can still do what you want without too many headaches. See my edit please

Comment: Thank you again for answering. I just came up with a way, I just want to describe it, and get your comment on it. I don't even know if it is legal to do what i thought in C#, I think C++ allows that.
Here it is:
I found a way to create an abstract class . In it I have an enum that stores the type of the derived class for each instance. so all "fruit classes" will derive from parent, and set their type in their constructor. later I will be adding parent instances to the "Basket", and use casting to resolve the actual instance.

class abstract parent
{
}

Answer (score 1):

C# doesn't have templates, but it does have [generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx), which is a similar concept. You're pretty close, but your `Fruit` class doesn't need to be generic at all. Just make sure all your `Lemon`, `Apple` and `Peach` classes inherit from `Fruit`:

```
class Fruit
{
    public int color;
    public Fruit() { } // default constructor for generic constrain below
}
class Lemon : Fruit
{
    //....
    public Lemon() : base() { } 
}
class Apple : Fruit
{
    //....
    public Apple() : base() { } 
}
class Peach : Fruit
{
    //....
    public Peach() : base() { } 
}
```

Now you can design your `Basket` class with a [generic constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) like this:

```
class Basket
{
    List<Fruit> FruitList = new List<Fruit>();

    public void AddFruit<T>(int c) where T : Fruit, new()
    {
        fru = new T();
        fru.color = c;
        FruitList.Add(fru);
    }
}

Basket basket = new Basket();
basket.Add<Apple>(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

In C# they are called Generic Methods not Template Methods since they are not generated for each time in compile time.

As for your example:

```
class Lemon : Fruit
{
    public Lemon(int c = 0) : base(c){}
    //....
}
class Apple : Fruit
{
    public Apple (int c = 0) : base(c){}
    //....
}
class Peach : Fruit
{
    public Peach (int c = 0) : base(c){}
    //....
}

class Fruit
{
    public int color;
    public Fruit(int c){ color = c; }
}

class Basket
{
    List<Fruit> fruits = new List<Fruit>();

    public void AddFruit(Fruit f)
    {
        fruits.Add(f);
    }

    public void CreateFruit<T>(int c) : where T : Fruit
    {
        Fruit f = Activator.CreateInstance<T>() as Fruit;
        f.color = c;
        fruits.Add(f);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you again for answering. I just came up with a way, I just want to describe it, and get your comment on it. I don't even know if it is legal to do what i thought in C#, I think C++ allows that.
Here it is:
I found a way to create an abstract class . In it I have an enum that stores the type of the derived class for each instance. so all "fruit classes" will derive from parent, and set their type in their constructor. later I will be adding parent instances to the "Basket", and use casting to resolve the actual instance.

```
class abstract parent
{
    public enum fruitType{lemon,apple,microsoft};
    public fruitType myType;
    public int ID;
}

class Lemon : parent
{
   Lemon(int i){ID=i;myType=fruitType.lemon};
   // various Lemon functions
}
class Apple: parent
{
   Apple(int i){ID=i;myType=fruitType.apple};
   // various Apple functions
}

then comes the Array:
class Basket
{
   public List<parent> basket=new List<parent>();
   void AddToBasket(parent p)
   {
    basket.Add(p);
   }

}
And in main:

class pgm
{
   void main()
   {
    Basket bsk=new Basket();
    parent pnt=new parent();
    Lemon  lmn=new Lemon();
    bsk.AddToBasket(lmn);// is this OK?

   }
}
```

when I need to read back the contents of basket, I will read it as parent, check "myType" and decide what fruit that parent is.
If this works (as it is now, or with minor changes) it works for me.